# How do I produce an event to the topic in cluster2 from a consumer (cluster1) after some transition in the data?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am just a beginner in Kafka. I need to consume kafka events from 2 different topics (A and A1) in PROD cluster and using the event payload I need to hit one REST api. The result from the rest api should be pushed into topic B in QA cluster. What could be the right approach for this problem statement?

I get to know that kafka streams will only work with the topics in same cluster. What else can I use for my problem statement?

Comment: I am not sure about publishing to different cluster works or not. But I would suggest to create a new endpoint which can publish to second cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Spring for Apache Kafka. Simply define the producer and consumer factories with different bootstrap servers.

If you are using Spring Boot, it's even easier because you can just configure the clusters using properties.

https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka

Comment: Thanks @Gary Russell. In that case I can use @ SendTo with the listener to publish into the topic in different cluster just by setting up the setReplyTemplate right? (Its going to be millions of kafka events in my case)

Comment: Yes; that will work - but transactions (exactly once semantics) won't work because transactions can't span clusters.

Comment: How can we achieve that?

Comment: You cannot. EOS requires the consumer offsets to be committed by the producer instead of the consumer. Since the producer is in a different cluster, it’s impossible. If the send fails the record will be redelivered (by default), if you wait for the send result, so you will get similar semantics, but it is not actually a transactional operation.